# Monero GUI startup (on Linux) getting *** Error in `./monero-wallet-gui': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f2afd1b9c60 ***

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Downloaded monero gui v12 on ubuntu and ran the command:

./monerod

then

./monero-wallet-gui

And now i get this error:

```
app startd
available width:  2495
available height:  1286
devicePixelRatio:  1
screen height:  2560
screen width:  1310
screen logical dpi:  96
screen Physical dpi:  95.9689
screen calculated ratio:  0.749757
*** Error in `./monero-wallet-gui': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f2afd1b9c60 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you provide the response from running `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux root 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this issue (which is related to OpenGL) by starting the GUI as follows:

`QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui`

This ensures the GUI uses the Qt Quick 2D Renderer instead of relying on OpenGL. More information about the Qt Quick 2D Renderer can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/QtQuick2DRenderer/).

> Qt Quick 2D Renderer is an alternative renderer for Qt Quick 2 that uses the Raster paint engine to render the contents of the scene graph instead of OpenGL. As a result of not using OpenGL to render the scene graph, some features and optimizations are no longer available. Most Qt Quick 2 applications will run without modification though any attempts to use unsupported features will be ignored. By using the Qt Quick 2D Renderer it is now possible to run Qt Quick 2 applications on hardware and platforms that do not have OpenGL support.
>
> Qt Quick 2D Renderer is a Qt module that contains a scene graph renderer plugin.

Comment: Does this mean my gui runs slower? what does this impact? I'm on a virtualbox machine. could that be why?

Comment: It doesn't affect performance as far as I know. The GUI might look a bit less aesthetic though. Like I said, it ensures the GUI falls back to the Qt Quick 2D Renderer to render graphics. Using the GUI in a VM is probably the cause of it not being able to start normally.